# MySQL select in one row values from the other row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a supersimple query `SELECT TIME, VALUE, TYPE from mylog`;

My query show the next:

```
| TIME            | VALUE |      TYPE |
 -------------------------------------
| 2013-09-26 04:45|  18.7 |         1 |
| 2013-09-26 04:45|  84.5 |         2 |
| 2013-09-26 05:00|  18.6 |         1 |
| 2013-09-26 05:00|  84.7 |         2 |
```

But I want the query show the next:

```
| TIME            | VALUE A |  VALUE B  |  
 ----------------------------------------
| 2013-09-26 04:45|  18.7   |  85.5     |  
| 2013-09-26 05:00|  18.6   |  84.7     |
```

where `VALUE A` is `Type = 1` and `VALUE B` is `Type = 2`

All data is stored in a just one table, and contains the columns:

```
TIME, VALUE, TYPE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `TIME`,
  MIN(IF(`TYPE`=1,`VALUE`,99999999)) AS `Value A`,
  MIN(IF(`TYPE`=2,`VALUE`,99999999)) AS `Value B`
FROM mylog
GROUP BY `TIME`
```

with `99999999` menaing "no value available"

**EDIT**

I do no use NULL, as it will deny me the `MIN`(or `MAX`). If you want NULL instead, you must wraop this in

```
SELECT `TIME`, 
  IF(`Value A`=99999999,NULL,`Value A`),
  IF(`Value B`=99999999,NULL,`Value B`)
FROM (
   -- ...
) AS baseview
```

Comment: Why 99999999 and not 0 or NULL when there is "no value available" like it should can you elaborate why you choose 99999999??

Comment: 99999999 and 0 are something like the same thing - I didn't know, if negative values can happen, so I chose "off scale high" as a marker. NULL will not work with `MIN` or `MAX`. See my edit!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIME,
MIN(CASE WHEN TYPE= '1' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END)   AS VALUE_A,
MIN(CASE WHEN TYPE= '2' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END)   AS VALUE_B From mylog GROUP BY time
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af79e/20)

Comment: +1 but still the CASE WHEN TYPE= '1' should be CASE WHEN TYPE= 1   to avoid casting..